# Better way to solve $\cos\left(\frac{\gamma'}{2}\right) = g_0$ and $e^{i\beta'} \sin\left(\frac{\gamma'}{2}\right) = g_1$ for $\gamma',\beta'$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve the two equations to solve for:
$\gamma',\beta'$:
\begin{align}
\cos\left(\frac{\gamma'}{2}\right) = g_0\qquad e^{i\beta'}\sin\left(\frac{\gamma'}{2}\right) = g_1
\end{align}
Where $g_0$ is real, and  $g_1$ is some complex number. I tried
\begin{align*}
\gamma'=2\cos^{-1}(g_0),\qquad\cos(\beta')\sin\left(\frac{\gamma'}{2}\right)=Re(g_1),\ \text{(or)}\ \sin(\beta')\sin\left(\frac{\gamma'}{2}\right)=Im(g_1)
\end{align*}
Then for each $\gamma'$, there should be two corresponding $\beta'$s. However, it turned out that my solution doesn't quite work. I'm wondering is there another way I can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you make that "or" an "and" you get one solution for $\beta'$. What makes you say this doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^{i\beta}=\pm\frac{g_1}{\sqrt{1-g_0^2}}$$ and $$\beta=-i\log\frac{g_1}{\sqrt{1-g_0^2}}+k\pi.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Should the sign of the first term of $\beta$ be $\pm$?

Comment: @ZR-: why should it ?

Answer (score 2):

Solve one for $\sin{\frac{\gamma '}{2}}$, solve the other for $\cos{\frac{\gamma '}{2}}$, and then use $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $\gamma^\prime\pm2\arccos g_0(\mod4\pi)$, which is consistent with $\sin\tfrac{\gamma^\prime}{2}=\pm|g_1|$ iff $g_0^2+|g_1|^2=1$, in which case $e^{i\beta^\prime}=\operatorname{sgn}g_1$ (except for the case $g_0=\pm1,\,g_1=0$, where $\beta^\prime$ is arbitrary). This constrains $\beta^\prime$ to either the even or odd multiples of $\pi$.